# How to add errors to nested models with Rails 4, visible in field_with_errors div and errors array at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Expense with a has_many relation to expense_details. 
Within Expense model I make controls and I add errors to Expense and its nested attributes.

The error is that need to add the error twice:

-One to make appears field_with_errors div

-The other for displaying the errors through instance variable

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :expense_details, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_details,  :allow_destroy => :true
 validate :control_teletrabajo

 def control_teletrabajo
   expense_details.each do |expense_detail|
   if control_fails
      # first:
      errors["expense_details.expense_month"] << "error message")
      # second: 
      expense_detail.errors.add(:expense_month) 
   end
 end
```

I would like to use only the second one, as this:

```
 expense_detail.errors.add(:expense_month,"error message")
```

but this sentence, doesn't add the error to the errors array of the @expense instance variable: **@expense.errors**, so is not displayed. This sentence generates the "field_with_errors" div

The other one `errors["expense_details.expense_month"] << "error message")`, makes appears "error message" to @expense.errors but doesn't generate "div_with_errors" div

Comment: You mention that `:teletrabajo_repetido` is automatically translated, but just to rule out any issues with your locale file or the translation process, what happens if you just use a string instead, e.g. `expense_detail.errors.add(:expense_month, 'test error string')`.

Comment: perhaps I have not explained well, in the first block of code, it doesn't matter if I put expense_detail.errors.add(:expense_month,"string error") or expense_detail.errors.add(:expense_month, :msg_error): It doesn't add the error to the errors array, after @expense save, (@expense.error doesn't contain the expense_month error)

Comment: I've edited the question, to make it more readable. Please take a look now. Thanks

Comment: You can try validates_associated. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: Well, the solution was in make a good use validations, `using inverse_of`, `validates_associated` it seems is not necessary (if I put this, the nested model is validated twice.... I'm still studying this). And also,  puting the nested model validations in its place